# Formatting email sent with Contact form

Tags: theming, forms, 8, emails

I created a custom form (adding some additional fields) using the **Contact module** from the core of **Drupal 8**.

When I submit the form is sent an **email** containing all values, but it is really **bad formatted**. The email only contains form's values without any field label and it is **unreadable**.

How can I customize the template of the email sent on the form's submit?

---

### What I already tried

#### hook_mail_alter

I found some answer about the same problem for Drupal 7 suggesting to implement a custom `hook_mail_alter` function (for example: [1](https://www.drupal.org/node/1212144#comment-4710770), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3378209/3763649)).

So I created a custom module with my function:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter().
 */
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) {

  // Process only 'contact_page_mail' messages
  if ($message['id'] != 'contact_page_mail') {
    return;
  }

  $params = $message['params'];

  // Body
  $message['body'] = [];
  $message['body'][] = t('Some custom message');

  // I don't know what should I do here?
  // How can I access values of all fields in the form?
  // ...

  return;
}
```

The function is correctly triggered before the email is sent, but I can't access field's values so I'm not able to build a custom email.

Also I can't get the form's id (only a generic `'contact_page_mail'` valid on all contact forms) so I'm not able to handle different contact forms in this function.

#### Swift Mailer

As suggested in [this other similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193382/how-can-i-theme-the-outgoing-contact-mail), I tried with the [Swift Mailer module](https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer).

After [some effort](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/199464/60010), I'm able to get it working and now I have a `swiftmailer.html.twig` template file with this content:

```
<div>

  {{ body }}

</div>
```

But as for the `hook_mail_alter` solution, I don't know how to access form's field values so I can't customize the email format.

Moreover, the Swift Mailer module currently is an *alpha* version (8.x-1.0-alpha1) and the Mailsystem module (required to get things working) is a *beta* version. So I would like to avoid to install unstable modules on a production website (anyway this can be the last solution, if no other works).

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Berdir, now within the `hook_mail_alter` function I can access field values with:

```
$contactMessage = $message['params']['contact_message'];

// Value of 'field_my_field_name'
$contactMessage->get('field_my_field_name')->getString();
```

So I can put them inside the `$message['body']`.

Quite complicated, but it works.

Is there a way to get field values within the Swift Mailer template? I tried with `{{ params.contact_message.field_work_with_us_name }}` but it doesn't works.

What happen if I have two or more contact forms? The function `hook_mail_alter` will be triggered on all of them. Is there a way to have a specific function for each contact form?

Comment: @Berdir I edited my question. The question you pointed out is very similar and I tried to be more specific (showing what I already tried). Also, none of those solutions answer my question.

Comment: $message['params]['contact_message'] contains the entity. You can also try hook_contact_message_view(), that's similar to hook_node_view() and you should be able to set a custom #theme there and/or alter the formatted fields.

Comment: Also, if you are using Drupal 8 now, I doubt there is a way around using beta modules at the moment. I'm using both in production for more than a year now. And I maintain mailsystem and plan to do a stable release soon.

Comment: Thank you @Berdir. Please, take a look to my last edit. Do you know if is there a way to have a specific `hook_mail_alter` function for different contact forms?

Comment: The bundle() of the message entity is the form

Comment: @Berdir Thank you again, the `bundle()` method does what I needed. If you want to put your comments inside an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Andrea: Did you had trouble with the html of the mail body? I added a #theme key to the build array like Berdir suggested but although my outgoing mail has the content-type "text/html", the body part seems to be handled as plain text, because html tags are removed.

Comment: @PhilippMichael Sadly I ended up to use plain text since I was not able to send as html. I think this is an annoying drawback in Drupal. Let me know if you find the right way.

Comment: Yes, in a perfect world I would just have to create a twig file for the view mode 'mail'. I will tell you if find a proper way to send html mail with contact form. Thanks for your quick reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting together an answer based on the comments/discussion there so this can be accepted/closed.

- General instructions on how to theme a mail can be found in this existing answer: [How can I theme the outgoing contact mail?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193382/how-can-i-theme-the-outgoing-contact-mai)
- You might want to watch https://www.drupal.org/node/2680731, once resolved, you can rely on that instead of your own custom code to send the mail as HTML.
- To use a custom template for the inner parts of the mail, you can set a custom template in `hook_contact_message_view()`. Or use field templates for specific fields.
- To check for a specific contact form, you can use the `bundle()` method of the contact message entity, which you can find in `$message['params]['contact_message']` in `hook_mail_alter()`. Make sure you combine this with a check that it is there and an entity object, otherwise you could have fatal errors for other mails.

Comment: For others wondering about `hook_contact_message_view`: It implements [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8.2.x)